# Resolving unknown type of nested class in parent class when it's used as a type parameter in a child class's method

Tags: c++

This isn't a "should you do this" pattern question, but I stumbled on this case, and I'm having a hard time finding in the C++ spec where the rules are applied for the following situation:

```
//--------------tester.cc----------
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

int main() {
  B b;
  b.foo(std::vector<A::C>{{}});
  return 0;
}

//-------------A.h-----------------
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

class A {
 public:
  struct C {
  };
};

#endif

//--------------B.h----------------
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

#include "A.h"
#include <vector>

class B : public A {
 public:
  std::vector<C> foo(std::vector<C> bar);
};

#endif

//---------------B.cc--------------
#include "B.h"
#include <iostream>

std::vector<C> B::foo(std::vector<C> bar) {
  std::cout << "I'm being called" << std::endl;
  return bar;
}
```

In the above case, if I try and compile the program with `clang++ -std=c++14 B.cc tester.cc -o text.exe` and run `test.exe`, I get the error "unknown type name 'C'; did you mean 'A::C'", on the return type of `B::foo`.

If I change the return type of `B::foo` to be `std::vector<A::C>` in the header and source files for B, it compiles and runs (which totally makes sense).

What doesn't make sense to me is why the same scoping syntax (if that is the right word) is not necessary when `std::vector<C>` is used as a parameter for the same method?

Conceptually it seems not too surprising since B is a child class of A (the parameter type as written above would not work if B didn't inherit A), but can anybody point me in the direction towards an explanation of what is actually happening with the language here?

Comment: What? @user4571301 this is not a duplicate of that question. This question asks why it's not necessary to use scope resolution for the formal parameter.

Comment: super helpful. Thanks @user4581301. But can you point me towards which assumptions are specifically made, and in what order they are made?

Comment: @purag I initially dropped the dupe as a comment and called it an evil twin, but in reread of the chosen answer, the Asker's question was also covered.  The point is hammered home in the second answer which demonstrates if you use a trailing return type scope is not required. Bogu Wei, I suspect this is done to allow a simpler parser.  C++ is a single-pass compiler, so it reads and processes everything as it finds it. When the compiler reaches and processes the return type it does not yet know the function is a method of `B` and cannot yet use the scope of `B` to aid in look-up.

Comment: But by the time it has reached the parameters, `B::` has been parsed and the compiler now knows the function is a method of `B` and can take advantage of `B` to simplify look-up.

Comment: @user4581301 ahh, I see. sorry for being quick to judge!